# Keras can't save model with CuDNNLSTM as SavedModel

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have recently encountered a problem with Keras. My model looks like:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(max_sequence_len,))

# Embedding layer
embedding = Embedding(
        input_length=max_sequence_len,
        input_dim=len(word_idx),
        output_dim=100,
        weights=[embedding_matrix],
        trainable=False
)(inputs)

# Recurrent layers
heart = Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(256))(embedding)

dense = Dense((n_of_stocks * stock_size * 4), activation='relu')(heart)

# Fully connected layer
preoutput = []
outputs = []
for i in range(n_of_stocks):
    preoutput.append(Dense(stock_size * 4, activation='linear')(dense))
    outputs.append(Reshape((stock_size, 4))(preoutput[i]))

# Compile the model
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="the_model")

model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.save("mynetwork")
```

When I try to save model it fails with an error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\Project T\neural\network.py", line 95, in <module>
    model.save("mynetwork")
  File "C:\Users\nkart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\nkart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\rnn\base_rnn.py", line 282, in _use_input_spec_as_call_signature
    if self.unroll:
AttributeError: 'CuDNNLSTM' object has no attribute 'unroll'
```

Am I doing something wrong? Should I try to save it as h5?

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you've used instead of just the error? `AttributeError: 'CuDNNLSTM' object has no attribute 'unroll'` probably because `CuDNNLSTM` is a layer, and not a model.

Comment: @Djinn, just added the code. Yes, I use CuDNNLSTM as a layer, I am new to neural networks and as far as I understand it is just an accelerated equivalent of an LSTM, which is using GPU

Comment: The error is where you tried to save the model. Your updated question still doesn't show that.

Comment: @Djinn added that as well, I am not doing anything special rather than `model.save("mynetwork")`

Comment: How did you import `CuDNNLSTM`? And what version tensorflow are you using?

Comment: @Djinn `from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout, Masking, Embedding, CuDNNLSTM, Bidirectional, Reshape, Flatten, Input`
TensorFlow v2.9.1
Cuda v11.2.0
CuDNN v8.1

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `CuDNNLSTM`, just use `LSTM` (which is newer) with default parameters, it will automatically use CuDNN, assuming you have CuDNN properly installed. `CuDNNLSTM` is for Tensorflow <=2.0.

```
heart = Bidirectional(LSTM(256))(embedding)
```

You might need to use `tensorflow.keras.layers` instead of `keras.layers`.